# Pull dropdown to the left when Bootstrap navbar is collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 in an app dashboard and I'm facing a problem using navbar. I added a dropdown menu that is being shown correctly, but once I resize the window and the navbar is collapsed, it is showed at the left instead that at the right. What can I do to solve it?

Here you can find an screenshot with the problem and what I need, and some code:

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
</div>

<c:if test="${not empty username}">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown">${username} <span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="<c:url value='/logout' />">Logout</a></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `navbar` collapses at 768px, so this media query will float your `navbar-nav` to the right once the `navbar` is collapsed.

[Here is a jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/uWBP3/3/)

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe setting `text-align:right` would provide a better end result